# Output a range of columns from a file, where the range is set by two variables

Tags: text-processing

I want to output a range of columns from a file, where the range is set by two variables.

Really struggling with this. I imagine cut is the best tool, but as far as I'm aware it doesn't accept variables to designate the range.

It's a tab delimited file. I've tried:

```
Column=8401    

awk -F $'\t' -v c=$Column '{ for (x=1; x<=c; x++) {  printf "%s\n", $x } }' ~/file.txt > ~/file1.txt
```

But that doesn't work (aim being to select the column range of 1 to 8401).

To give an example of Input and Output:

```
ColumnStart=1    
ColumnEnd=3
```

Input:

```
12   33   55   23   13   88
```

Using the `$column` variable I would output `$ColumnStart` to `$ColumnEnd`

Output:

```
12   33   55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the variables like this:

```
cut -f${ColumnStart}-${ColumnEnd}
```

(assuming the variables always contain appropriate values...).

Comment: Well I'll be a monkeys uncle! Brilliant, thank you. I've used similar methods to separate variables from things, but didn't even try it in cut because i spoke to a number of people that said cut wouldn't except a variable unless its input being piped into it!

Comment: It works because the variable is expanded by the shell before the argument is passed to `cut`.